# Adding the apache user to my default group doesn't give apache group access

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions, groups

The whole Linux user:group topic just gives me headaches again.

#### Situation

I have my document roots (httpdocs) and everything inside chown-ed to a certain user and a certain group, let's say `myuser:mygroup`.

```
chown -R myuser:mygroup httpdocs
```

Now apache doesn't have access to let's say a public images folder. So I add apache to mygroup, for example with:

```
usermod -a -G mygroup apache
```

#### Question

Any file or folder which I chmod to 775 should now give apache write permission, not?
Doesn't happen... do I have to reload, restart or else reinitiate something for this to happen or do I still just not get the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

Did you restart apache after making the change?  The groups will only be enumerated for the apache account when apache server is restarted.

Comment: no I didn't... so there must be another way to cause the enumeration...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just realized that it works as I described it. Don't know why the lag, maybe I just didn't properly refresh the browser or maybe CentOS reads the group file after every X minutes or who knows. But the scenario as I described it, works.